# How to make undocumented SpecFlow tests fail (not be marked inconclusive) when using Jenkins and NUnit?

Tags: jenkins, nunit, specflow

We use SpecFlow and NUnit in Visual Studio at work. Very useful, etc, etc. Once we've finished development the checked in code goes to a build server which uses Jenkins to build and run all the tests. Very helpful, etc.

However, there is an annoying hole: if you a/ use a step in SpecFlow that you *don't* define, a default step definition is used which marks the test as Inconclusive, and then b/ NUnit ignores Inconclusive tests (apparently MSTest fails them instead), and then c/ Jenkins doesn't detect a problem and passes the build. This means our build servers can pass tests that aren't even defined correctly.

So, can anyone EITHER:
  - tell me how get SpecFlow to throw errors on missing steps? (can't find an option for it or anything on the web) OR:
  - tell me how to get NUnit to treat Inconclusive tests as failing? (once more, can't find an option for it or anything on the web) OR:
  - somehow get Jenkins to pick up the Inconclusive results and treat that as failing?

All suggestions will be considered, left-field ones included! Thank you.

Comment: Look at: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Configuration - there is a configuration option available....

Comment: Looks like you have a good answer. Here is some background as to why the problem exists... NUnit has four fundamental result statuses: Passed, Failed, Skipped and Inconclusive. MsTest and Visual Studio have three. Inconclusive for us means "this gives no information at all regarding failure or success" so it is certainly not what you want for a missing step.

Answer (score 5):

There is a configuration option to change this behavior.

See [here](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Installation/Configuration.html) for the documentation. The configuration we're interested in here is `missingOrPendingStepsOutcome`.

The default setting is:

```
missingOrPendingStepsOutcome="Inconclusive"
```

We simply need to change (or add the setting) as follows:

```
missingOrPendingStepsOutcome="Error"
```

Comment: Just an FYI for the future; comments are not permanent and may be removed in the future. It's better to put all relevant details into your answer rather than just referencing your comment. Cheers!

Comment: I ran into this same issue, and after setting missingOrPendingStepsOutcome="Error" it's now failing those test scenarios when running them on Visual Studio, but still skipping them when running them on Azure DevOps (running VSTest).

Comment: Add this to your Specflow.json:
  "runtime": {
    "missingOrPendingStepsOutcome": "Error"
  }